# How can I define a "system-wide" constant that is a string containing a the directory of a specific folder?

Tags: php, apache

I store all of my scripts in the same place on the server and reference then using PHP include statements. But what if I want or need to change that directory? Do I really want to change every statement? Absolutely not.

One thing that I debated doing was to include a file named 'scriptsdir.php' that would be in the home directory for easy access. All this file would be responsible of doing is to define the constant 'SCRIPTS_DIR' as that directory. This suffices but if THAT file has to be moved or something happens to it, etc. I was wondering if I could define a constant that would be accessible without ever having to manually define it.

Is there a way to do this in php.ini or .htaccess or *anything*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to declare a *variable* `$_SERVER["SCRIPTS_DIR"]` via `.htaccess` using:

```
 SetEnv SCRIPTS_DIR /var/www/project123/includes/
```

That would be available reliably to all scripts beneath the document_root and can often simplify relocations.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with a [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)...

```
define('DOCROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

If using >= PHP 5.3 you can simply use `__DIR__`.

Then you would include your files using...

```
include DOCROOT . '/bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: Doesn't `dirname()` just return the parent directory?

Comment: @Tyler It determines the directory portion of a path from a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you require it to be system-wide across *all* PHP applications then you can use [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) with a file you define it in.